# R code: Plot multiple lines in one graph

Tags: r

I need to produce a line graph with two lines into the graph, one for the return of an asset and the other for a "Compound" factor, on the X axis you will have the days. My current code is the following:

```
lines(1:64,dataf[,3])
lines(1:64,data2$Change)
```

This of course gives me two line graphs, but I would like to have one graph with 1:64 (the days) on the X axis and "dataf[,3]" plus "data2$Change" as lines, can someone help me? thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You should first use plot() to create a new plot. `lines()` will add your line to the existing plot. Example:

```
plot(x = seq(1:10), y = seq(1:10),type = "l",col = "red")
lines(x = seq(1,10), y = seq(1,20,by=2), col = "green")
```

[image]